# PHP Getting Scores From A File

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have an htm file that holds scores for a game. I need to find each score above a 65, insert those scores and names only into a db and then print the entire file on the page with the high score lines in red. The htm file includes simple text:

```
<pre>
Thursday Afternoon Pairs Thursday Aft Session February 1, 2018

Scores after  5 rounds  Average:   50.0      Section  A  North-South

Pair    Pct   Score      Section Rank      MPs     

                         A     B     C  

  5   65.00   65.00  A   1                0.50(A)  Joseph - Marlene

  1   47.00   47.00  B  2/3    1          0.30(A)  Janet - Mina

  3   47.00   47.00  A  2/3               0.30(A)  Renee - Reichle
</pre>
```

There is no other tags in the file and the file cannot be modified.

I've only gotten as far as trying to find the highscores and see if I can get those to print.  This returns no matches found everytime.

```
$file = 108911.htm;
$pct = "([1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{2})";
$highgame_pct = 65; 

$contents = file_get_contents($file);

$pattern = preg_quote($pct, '/');

$pattern = "/^.*$pct.*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches) >= $highgame_pct){
   echo "Found matches:<br />";
   echo implode("<br />\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Comment: If you do a `preg_quote()` on your pattern, how would you be able to use it? It would search for content that _literally_ matches the string `([1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{2})`. If you're manually hard coding the pattern, there's never any reason to use that function.

Comment: Btw, `preg_match_all()` doesn't return the matched values, it returns the number of matches so your if-statement doesn't really make sense. [Check the manual on how to use that function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

Like anything, there are a lots of ways to do this, here is one to try:

```
# Set the threshold
$max    =   65;
# This will fetch file to array, trim spaces, then remove empty
# using file() will take the file and automatically turn it to an array
$arr    =   array_filter(file('108911.htm',FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES),function($v){
    return (!empty(trim($v)));
});
# This will iterate and find matched values based on pattern
$file   =   array_values(array_filter(array_map(function($v) use ($max){
    # Find values that match decimal pattern (allows 1 to 3 whole numbers and up to 2 decimal points)
    preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}/',$v,$match);
    # Checks if there are at least 3 values in matched array
    $match  =   (!empty($match[0]) && count($match[0]) == 3)? $match[0] : false;
    # If not, just return empty
    if(empty($match))
        return false;
    # If the second value (Points) is less than the max, return empty
    if($match[1] < $max)
        return false;
    # Get the name value
    preg_match('/[\w]+ - [\w]+/',$v,$name);
    # Return the points and the name
    return [
        'points' => $match[1],
        'name'  => $name[0]
    ];

},$arr)));
# Here is the raw array. You can loop this now to get the rows to insert
print_r($file);
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [points] => 65.00
            [name] => Joseph - Marlene
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you!  and if I wanted it to take the scores from the PCT column instead?

Comment: You just change `'points' => $match[1]` to `'points' => $match[0]`

Comment: Managed to get entire row of each match but it's only turning the last match red.  How do I get it to turn all matches red?  Here is what I changed and foreach statement:

Comment: Let me test what you have...one minute

Comment: `#gets entire row
 preg_match('/(.*) - (.*)/',$v, $wholelinescore);
 # Return the points and the name 
    return [
        'points' => $match[0],
        'name'  => $name[0], 
  'entirety' => $wholelinescore[0]
    ];
 
 

},$arr)));
   
foreach($file as $item) {
    $myline = $item['entirety'];
 $newline = "<span style='color: red;'>" . $myline . '</span>';
    $newphrase = str_replace($myline, $newline, $arr);
}
   
echo '<pre>' . implode($newphrase) . '</pre>';`

Comment: Oh, you need to do an array push `$newphrase[] = str_replace($myline, $newline, $arr);` then implode with a glue `echo implode('',$newphrase);`

Comment: getting `Notice: Array to string conversion` error and outputs `<pre>ArrayArrayArray</pre>`

Comment: That shouldn't be. If `$newline` is a string, and you are saving each string into the array `$newphrase`, then it should `implode()` an array of strings.

Comment: Thats what I thought.  especially since `echo $item['entirety']` prints out all matches.  maybe that's where I'm going wrong?  assigning `$item['entirety]` to a var?

Comment: What is `$item['entirety]`? if you `print_r($item['entirety]);` what is it? A string or an array?

Comment: Ok, you are replacing on an array (`$arr`). That won't work. `$arr` has to be a string to use `str_replace()`. What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: oh.... yeah, i'm trying to replace the matched lines in the file and then output the entire file (`$arr`) again.

Answer (score 0):

**preg_match_all** returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

Using similar regex pattern and using callback function to filter array:

```
# define array filter callback function
function filterArray($value1){
    return ($value1 >= 65.00);
}


# read file 
$file = "108911.htm";
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

# define regex
$pattern = "/(\d{2}\.\d{2})/m";

# find matches 
$val = preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches);
echo "Count of matches = $val\n";

# filter matches array 
$filteredArray = array_filter($matches[0], 'filterArray');

# print matched element
if (count($filteredArray) > 0) {
   echo "Found matches bigger or equal to 65.00:<br />";
   echo implode("<br />\n", $filteredArray);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Output:

```
Count of matches = 10
Found matches bigger or equal to 65.00:<br />
65.00<br />
65.00
```

You still need to modify this to match the "Score" column only.